# Angular - Changing data from 2 fields

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a form where a field (or just a display, the revenue) depends on 2 other fields (number and price).

I tried something I found on a tutorial that made a count of changes and tried to upgrade it to my trial.

On my html:

```
<div>
  <h3>You can win {{changeCount}} so far.</h3>
  <input
    type="number"
    id="price"
    (change)="changeCount =" + "{{price}} + " x " + {{number}} + ""
  placeholder="price" />
  <input
    type="number"
    id="number"
    (change)="changeCount =" + "{{price}} + " x " + {{number}} + ""
  placeholder="Nb de chambres" />
</div>
```

And my component.ts:

```
export class TestChangesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  price: number = 0;
  number: number = 0;
  changeCount: number = 0;
}
```

I might have mixed up the concatenation. I read it was the + symbol and tried to access the data  directly from the form but I will also try to hide the calculations later on on the ts file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use ngModel:

```
<div>
  <h3>You can win {{price * number}} so far.</h3>
  <input type="number" id="price" [(ngModel)]="price" placeholder="price" />
  <input
    type="number"
    id="number"
    [(ngModel)]="number"
    placeholder="Nb de chambres"
  />
</div>
```

For this to work you have to import FormsModule in your respective module.

I created a sandbox show my solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-meadow-85930?file=/src/app/app.component.html